# "exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. in vs 2010

Tags: vb.net

hi When i try to save data to access 2007 database i got error like "exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" i am making project to take weight from scale and save it to database  please help me to solve error.

```
 Try
        Dim PRO As String
        Dim CONNSTRING As String
        Dim COMMAND As String
        Dim MYCONNECTION As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

        PRO = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\weight.accdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=weight"
        CONNSTRING = PRO
        MYCONNECTION.ConnectionString = CONNSTRING
        MYCONNECTION.Open()
        COMMAND = "insert into entry ([weight1],[date1],[time1],[weight2],[date2],[time2],[netweight],[vehicleno],[name],[contactno],[productname],[charge],[paymentstatus]) values ('" & weight1.Text & "','" & date1.Text & "','" & time1.Text & "','" & weight2.Text & "','" & date2.Text & "','" & time2.Text & "','" & netweight.Text & "','" & vehicleno.Text & "','" & custname.Text & "','" & contact.Text & "','" & Product.Text & "','" & charge.Text & "','" & status.Text & "')"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(COMMAND, MYCONNECTION)

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("weight1", CType(weight1.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("date1", CType(date1.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("time1", CType(time1.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("weight2", CType(weight2.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("date2", CType(date2.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("time2", CType(time2.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("netweight", CType(netweight.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("vehicleno", CType(vehicleno.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("name", CType(custname.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("contactno", CType(contact.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("productname", CType(Product.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("charge", CType(charge.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("paymentstatus", CType(status.Text, String)))
        MsgBox("Saved")
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        MYCONNECTION.Close()
        weight1.Clear()
        date1.Text = ""
        time1.Text = ""
        weight2.Clear()
        date2.Text = ""
        time2.Text = ""
        netweight.Clear()
        vehicleno.Text = ""
        custname.Text = ""
        contact.Text = ""
        Product.Text = ""
        charge.Clear()
        status.Text = ""
        weighttype.Focus()
        Call ticket()





    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: You are mixing two concepts here. The way you provide parameters and your command query don´t match.

Comment: A .Text property is normally a String. You don't need CType().

Answer (score 0):

Write your SQL code like this:

```vb
COMMAND = "insert into entry ([weight1]) values (@weight1)"
```

and then add the parameters like this:

```vb
cmd.Parameters.Add("@weight1", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = weight1.Text
```

Provide a parameter placeholder in the SQL and then use that as the name of the parameter when you add it. Specify the data type as well and, for variable-width types, the size as well. Set the `Value` or the parameter you just added.

As you're using the ACE OLE DB provider, the parameter names will actually be ignored, but you should use them for your the clarity of your code. You must ensure that parameters are added in the same order they appear in the SQL code.